# Adding logo to Wordpress header

Tags: php, css

I want to add a logo to my header for a website im building, where in this code would I put the image URL? The theme im using in Bones.

```
<!doctype html>

<!--[if lt IE 7]><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 7)&!(IEMobile)]><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 8)&!(IEMobile)]><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js">     <!--<![endif]-->

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <?php // force Internet Explorer to use the latest rendering engine available ?>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>

    <?php // mobile meta (hooray!) ?>
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <?php // icons & favicons (for more: http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/) ?>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.png">
    <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico">
    <![endif]-->
    <?php // or, set /favicon.ico for IE10 win ?>
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#f01d4f">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/win8-tile-icon.png">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#121212">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>">

    <?php // wordpress head functions ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <?php // end of wordpress head ?>

    <?php // drop Google Analytics Here ?>
    <?php // end analytics ?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
jQuery('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
  jQuery('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
     .next('img').fadeIn()
     .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
  3000);
});
    </script>

        <style type="text/css">
    .fadein { position:relative; width:500px; height:332px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
    </style>

    <div id="container">

        <header class="header" style="background-color:#E0EEE0;" role="banner" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">

            <div id="inner-header" class="wrap cf">

                <?php // to use a image just replace the bloginfo('name') with your img src and remove the surrounding <p> ?>
                <p id="logo" class="h1" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php bloginfo(''); ?></a></p>

                <?php // if you'd like to use the site description you can un-comment it below ?>
                <?php // bloginfo('description'); ?>


                <nav role="navigation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
                             'container' => false,                           // remove nav container
                             'container_class' => 'menu cf',                 // class of container (should you choose to use it)
                             'menu' => __( 'The Main Menu', 'bonestheme' ),  // nav name
                             'menu_class' => 'nav top-nav cf',               // adding custom nav class
                             'theme_location' => 'main-nav',                 // where it's located in the theme
                             'before' => '',                                 // before the menu
                               'after' => '',                                  // after the menu
                               'link_before' => '',                            // before each link
                               'link_after' => '',                             // after each link
                               'depth' => 0,                                   // limit the depth of the nav
                             'fallback_cb' => ''                             // fallback function (if there is one)
                    )); ?>

                    </nav>

                </div>

            </header>
```

Answer (score 4):

It says right there in the code:

```
<?php // to use a image just replace the bloginfo('name') with your img src and remove the surrounding <p> ?>
```

So just replace this line below that comment:

```
<p id="logo" class="h1" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php bloginfo(''); ?></a></p>
```

with this:

```
<p id="logo" class="h1" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" rel="nofollow"><img src="http://example.com/your/logo/url.jpg" title="Your logo" alt="Your logo"></a></p>
```

Comment: Okay, yeah I read to comment, just unsure how to go about it, haven't been using Wordpress that long

Comment: You just have to copy paste. What is you are not sure about ?